# Any way to pass parent container objects single statement assignment?

Tags: c#, collections, initialization

I was wondering if it is possible to pass a 'parent container' to an object initialization using single statement initialization? I am thinking about using this approach for hierarchical unit test variable assignments; thank you in advanced.

```
public class ParentObj
{
    public IList<ChildObj> Children { get; set; }
}

public class ChildObj
{
    private ParentObj Parent { get; set; }
    public ChildObj(ParentObj parentObj) => Parent = parentObj;
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var parents = new List<ParentObj>();
        var parent = new ParentObj();
        parent.Children.Add(new ChildObj(parent));
        parents.Add(parent);

        // Anyway to duplicate the above with this style of initialization?
        var moreParents = new List<ParentObj>
        {
            new ParentObj
            {
                Children = new List<ChildObj>
                {
                    //new ChildObj( [need a reference to the parentObj] );
                }
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: If `Children` isn't initialized, you'll get NRE in this line `parent.Children.Add(new ChildObj(parent));`

Answer (score 0):

No, because at the time the Children are constructed your code doesn't have a reference to the parent. It's like C# is holding all the references for you, and doing all the linking, and just giving you the one end result (moreParents) object and you place it into the only thing you have a named reference for

You could change things like this:

```
public class ParentObj
{
    private IList<ChildObj> _children;
    public IList<ChildObj> Children {
        get { return _children; }
        set {
            _children = value;
            foreach (ChildObj c in value)
                c.Parent = this;
         }
    }

}

public class ChildObj
{
    public ParentObj Parent { get; set; }
}
```

So that the parent of the child can be set later, and then this code will work out:

```
    var moreParents = new List<ParentObj>
    {
        new ParentObj
        {
            Children = new List<ChildObj>
            {
                new ChildObj(), new ChildObj()
            }
        }
    };
```

Because you do have a way of referring to the parent (`this`)

Really, if you want to have some simple way of creating parents and children you need to create something that constructs them, so it can make a parent, and then then children supplying that parent.. Kinda like what you had in your first example!

ps; I'm not a fan of the "parent" and "child" terms of reference for this structure; they're normally used for inheritance hierarchies, where Child is-a Parent, rather than for container hierarchies where Parent has-a Children